# Android API to check if call is Dialing or Active

Tags: android

Following are the states which it goes through in different scenarios:

**1) Answering Received call**

```
CALL_STATE_RINGING => CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK (After Answering call) => CALL_STATE_IDLE (After End call)
```

**2) Rejecting / Not Answering (Missed) Received call**

```
CALL_STATE_RINGING => CALL_STATE_IDLE (After End call)
```

**3) Dialing call**

```
CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK (After dialing) => CALL_STATE_IDLE (After End call)
```

How to catch situation when "dialing" call state become be "active" in Android?